# Quick question regarding format of if-elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

If I wanted a group of if elif statements to execute to a single order; for example:

```
if int(one[1]) == solution:
```

and

```
if int(two[1]) == solution:
```

to execute a a single statement:

```
print "Hello World"
```

What would be the best format and syntaxically correct way to input this?

I tried:

```
if int(two[1]) == solution::
    elif int(one[1]) == solution:
        print "Hello World"
```

and other variations but couldn't put my figure on a correct way to do it. Be gentle StackOverflow, I haven't been programming too long.

And the language I'm programming in is Python. 
Thanks!

UPDATE:

I think this is the correct answer, not AND Abdul Kader. Thank you both though. And in Python I think I'll be typing:

```
if (int(one[1]) == solution OR int(two[1])== solution)):
         print "Hello World"
```

Comment: The edit has made it sytactically wrong. You cannot put an 'elif' inside an 'if' block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to print it when **both** conditions are true you have to use `and`

```
if (int(one[1]) == solution) and (int(two[1]) == solution):
    print "Hello, world"
```

if you want to print it if **one ore more** condition is true you have to use `or` the same way

```
if (int(one[1]) == solution) or (int(two[1]) == solution):
    print "Hello, world"
```

You shouldn't have to use `elif`. At least if I understand you.

`elif` is for testing a different condition if the condition in the`if` statement is false, consider this pattern

```
if spam:
    do_eggs() # We arrive here if spam is true
elif ham:
    do_sausages() # Here if spam was false but ham is true
else:
    print "Camelot!" # And here if both were false
```

PS:

```
if spam:
    do_eggs()
elif ham:
    do_eggs()
```

would indeed be a twisted way of doing `if spam or ham: do_eggs()` but it really is ugly. **Dost thou not dare use this or thou shalt be blown to tiny bits**.

Answer (score 2):

```
if int(one[1]) == solution or int(two[1]) == solution:
    print "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (int(one[1]) == solution) and (int(two[1]) == solution):
   print 'Helloworld'
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an OR between them:

```
if (int(one[1]) == solution) or (int(two[1]) == solution)):
    print "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list instead of "or", which is handy when there are many choices.

```
if solution in [int(one[1]), int(two[1]), int(three[0])]:
```